# Retrieve Data from Mysql Database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps

I am trying to retrieve data from database which has the coordinates that i fill there, and i have a small web page that shows a map, but i need the longitude and latitude to be selected from the database before viewing it, so is it possible to connect and retrieve data in the java script?!

btw here's the wepage xml:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Map.aspx.cs" Inherits="Map2" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        //document.write("<?php echo 'hello'; ?>");

//select coordinates from Mysql DB
        var map;
        var geocoder;
        var marker;
        function InitializeMap() {

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(/*fetchedFromDB*/, /*fetchedFromDB*/);
            var myOptions =
            {
                zoom: 17,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(/*fetchedFromDB*/, /*fetchedFromDB*/), map: map });
        }

        window.onload = InitializeMap;

    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 504px">
    <table>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan ="2">
    <div id ="map" style="height: 529px; width: 1011px; margin-top: 0px;" >
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can't interact directly with a database using Javascript. You may do so through some API, but not directly. Also, what's with the PHP in your C#?

Comment: If you put your mysql login credentials into the html as javascript, wouldn't this mean that everyone is able to use this data and login to your server? Everyone can read your sourcecode. Everyone could access your database. you can access MySQL using JavaScript, but only serverside with node.js. You can fetch the data with C# tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this in an easy way, i retrieved the coordinates from database then i ran the script in code behind (inside the c# code) as shown:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class Map : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public static string latitude;
    public static string longitude;
    MySqlDataReader dr;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Server=XX;Port=3306;Database=XX;Uid=XX;Pwd=XX"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT latitude,longitude FROM coordinates";

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                latitude = dr[0].ToString();
                longitude = dr[1].ToString();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }


        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>");
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>"
            + "var map;" 
        + "var marker;" 
        + "function InitializeMap() {"
        + "var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(" + latitude + "," + longitude + ");"
        + "var myOptions ="
        + "{ zoom: 17, center: latlng,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,disableDefaultUI: true};"
        + "map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);"
        + "marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(" + latitude + ", " + longitude + "), map: map }); }"
        + "window.onload = InitializeMap;"

        + "</script>");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time the way is to just use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for such things.

Basically you need some server-side script that fetches data from database on request and returns it to javascript in some format (e.g. [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)). From client-side javascript you call this script via XMLHttpRequest when page gets loaded or when the users clicks some button etc.

Comment: Yea, i looked for the xmlHttpRequest but i guess it only gets 1 value?! because there's only xmlhttp.responseText !, how to get multiple data using this?

Comment: It's only one value for the whole response. But as I mentioned you can pack multiple values using JSON. It can hold lists, hashes, lists of hashes etc. If you are using .NET you can check out [this library](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to keep things simple.

Comment: I get it, thank you vbo!, i am thinking to do it with c# coding and to store the retrieved data in a hidden label and then select them in the script.. i'll give it a try.

Comment: OK. Good luck with this!

Answer (score 0):

You want to minimize the amount of area where two languages exchange data.  At most, put everything in a single object and convert it to json:

```
<?php
  $data = array( 'a' => $a );
?>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

Though the better route is to write a page that does nothing but output JSON data, then read it in with an AJAX call.

Comment: Hmm, there's a //document.write("<?php echo 'hello'; ?>"); in the OP.  I was looking at that.  Otherwise, same point for C#, just use different method to encode to json